# Clicking on username and going to profile

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I am using Parse as my back end and have a home view where all user's photos will go, kind of like a stream, each cell has a header with the user's username where you can click it and go to their profile. However I can't figure out how to access the user's information and bring it to the next view.. This is my code so far.

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    static NSString *headerIdentifier = @"headerIdentifier";
    UITableViewHeaderFooterView *headerView = [tableView dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier:headerIdentifier];

    if (headerView == nil) {
        headerView = [[UITableViewHeaderFooterView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake( 0.0f, 0.0f, self.view.bounds.size.width, 44.0f)];


        //Container to hold everything.
        self.containerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake( 0.0f, 0.0f, self.view.bounds.size.width, 44)];
        self.containerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [headerView.contentView addSubview:containerView];


        UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
        [button addTarget:self
                   action:@selector(viewProfile: user:)
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [button setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        button.frame = CGRectMake(8, 6, 100, 30);

        //Setting the username to button.
        PFObject *owner = [self.userPhotos objectAtIndex:section];
        PFUser *user = [owner objectForKey:@"user"];
        [user fetch];
        self.usernameHolder = user.username;
        [button setTitle:self.usernameHolder forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        [containerView addSubview:button];
    }

    return headerView;
}

- (void)viewProfile:(UIButton *)button user:(PFUser *)user {
    AccountView *accountView = [[AccountView alloc] init];
    [accountView setUser:user];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:accountView animated:YES];
}
```

When I do an NSLog on the accountView it comes back as null and am very confused!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think one issue is that the button isn't passing anything in the user parameter to the `-viewProfile:user` method.

As much as I hate using "magic numbers" for this sort of thing, what you probably need to do is use the `.tag` property on the button as an index to then lookup the `user` via the `userPhotos`. So...

Add in `-tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:`

```
button.tag = section
```

Change

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(viewProfile: user:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

to

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(viewProfile:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

And replace your `-viewProfile:user:` method with

```
- (void)viewProfile:(UIButton *)button {
  AccountView *accountView = [[AccountView alloc] init];
  PFObject *owner = [self.userPhotos objectAtIndex:button.tag];
  PFUser *user = [owner objectForKey:@"user"];
  [accountView setUser:user];
  [self.navigationController pushViewController:accountView animated:YES];
}
```

You may or may not need to fetch the user again - I'm not sure if the Parse SDK will update the user in userPhotos when you fetch it. You could also avoid the fetch altogether if you `.includeKey("user")` on your query to get the userPhotos.

Comment: my friend, I wanted to thank you for your help, it works wonderfully.

Comment: @DerekSaunders If it works for you, could you accept the answer?